# Predict Probability

Tags: r, variables, model, glm, predict

I need to use the predict() function in R to try and obtain the probability for a set of values. The dataset is as follows:

```
Loc: Beach, NonBeach
Sex: Male, Female

Infec: (Response variable)
```

with the glm:

```
mod1 = glm(Infec ~ Loc + Sex, family = binomial)
```

I am wanting to determine the probability value for all of these variables, these being, Male - Beach, Male - NonBeach, Female - Beach, Female - Nonbeach using predict.  I know I can use: the predict function in the following fashion:

```
predict(mod1, newdata = list(Loc = "Beach", Sex = "Female"), type = "response")
```

to get an answer for Beach and Female, but I am not sure how to get all 4 probabilities in the same outcome, like:

```
Female    Beach     xxx
Male      Beach     xxx
Female    NonBeach  xxx
Male      NonBeach  xxx
```

without the value being printed as many times as there are observations.

Comment: you want to predict by giving only value for one variable?

Comment: Your model cannot give you that answer, because it does not know what is the distribution of Swim and Age given Sex=Male and Loc=Beach. Imagine e.g. that all males at the beach were 15 years old; the prediction would be different to a scenario in which all males at the beach were 29 years old. You can try to run a different logistic regression with only Sex and Loc as your covariates and use that to make predictions, or you can try a Bayesian model (which lets you specify priors + gives posterior draws that can be used to obtain the conditional probability distribution you're after)

Comment: @konvas, Thank you for your reply. I was wondering if there was a way to somehow ignore the factor and count all instances of NumInfec including all of Age and Swim. As far as I have seen, the predict function cannot be used in this fashion.

Comment: I am not sure what you are aiming to do. The model you posted is a logistic regression and will give you the probability that Infec = 1 (I assume this is interpreted as the probability of infection?) given Swim, Loc, Age, Sex.  You mention counting instances of NumInfec which is a bit confusing.. maybe you were trying to run a Poisson regression instead?

Comment: I think you just need to construct the data frame with all the possibilities. Something like `p_data = expand.grid(Loc = levels(orig_data$Loc), Sex = levels(orig_data$Sex))`